# Microsoft Excel Date conversion

Tags: excel, date

i got a problem

i got data in excel which contains date in this format "**27/2/201**1"

i need to convert it into "**MMM, dd yyyy**" format, how i can do it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming value 27/02/2011 is in cell A1
The formula would be

```
=DATE(MID(A1,7,4),MID(A1,4,2),LEFT(A1,2))
```

This gives you a nice Excel date you can do anything else with like format, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in the worksheet, you can use the text function TEXT(reference, format)

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmm/dd/yyyy")
```

In VBA use the Format() function:

```
Sub a()
x = Format(Now(), "mmm,dd,yyyy")

End Sub
```

If the date is stored as a string in your sheet and doesn't use a 2-digit month, you can convert it to a date format like this:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A2,4), FIND("/",A2,FIND("/",A2)+1)-FIND("/",A2)-1,LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1))
```

Comment: this doesnot solve my problem for excel. i got text like this 27/02/2011 but when i use the formula above u given it does nothing. returns the original text. while if i use same formula for date 2/9/2012 its converting it into Feb/09/2012 which is not correct coz format is dd/mm/yyy

Comment: SO All the dates in the sheet are text values formatted as dd/m/yyyy, and you want to convert that to a date format...COrrect?

Comment: i found out that problem was with my system date format, it was US i changed it into UK then it worked out for me.